# TensorFlow multidimensional perceptron

Tags: tensorflow

I have a csv file with a 4 output rows (prefixed with _) and 225 input rows. The rest are normal:

```py
_y1,_y2,_y3,_y4,x1,x1,...,x225
[some assortment of 4 1s or 0s],[some random assortment of 1s or 0s]
```

With the code below I'm trying to have it learn (not really a classifier) which ys are 1 and 0 given the inputs and evaluate the input vs the prediction to compare against the training set. I'm not concerned about overtraining at the moment. Yes, I have 1 as the iteration count and I know that needs to be much larger, but until I get the results I expect (4-dimensional output) I don't care.

```py
with open(filename, 'rU') as fin:
    reader = csv.DictReader(fin)
    reader.next()
    features = [name for name in reader.fieldnames if not name.startswith('_')]
    outputs  = [name for name in reader.fieldnames if     name.startswith('_')]
    lines = []
    for line in reader:
        lines.append(line)
x_true = [ [float(line[feature]) for feature in features] for line in lines]
y_true = [ [float(line[output]) for output in outputs] for line in lines ]
w_true = np.random.rand(len(features), 1) # init weights
b_true = np.random.rand(1) # init bias

x_in = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, len(features)], "x_in")
w = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal((len(features), 1)), name="w")
b = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[]), name="b")
h = tf.add(tf.matmul(x_in, w), b, name="h")
y_in = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, len(outputs)], "y_in")
loss_op = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(tf.subtract(y_in, h)), name="loss")
train_op = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.3).minimize(loss_op)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for step in range(1):
        sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={
          x_in: x_true,
          y_in: y_true
        })

    w_computed = sess.run(w)
    b_computed = sess.run(b)

    pred = tf.add(tf.matmul(x_in, w), b)
    results = sess.run(pred, feed_dict={x_in: x_true})
    print "predictions", pred.eval({x_in: x_true})
    print len(x_true), len( results), [len(x) for x in results]
```

However I have a few problems. The first is I expect [225,4] outputs, but I only get [255,1] output from the eval() call.

Next is I am not sure how to evaluate a single row?
Should I be using estimator?
If I need another level, how do I convert this to a DNN?
Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do have a few problems, I'll try to list here as many as I can see and propose some possible solutions

#### Wrong number of outputs

You're defining your weight as a `(len(features), 1)` matrix, i.e., a row array. When you multiply this with your sample, you'll get 1 value as result, not 4.
To have 4, you need to define `w` with shape `(len(features), 4)` and `b` with shape `(4)`

#### Evaluate a single row

For that, you set your batch size to 1. This means that, assuming `row` is a numpy array with the row you want to process, you need to pass the `feed_dict={x_in: row[None,:]}`

Estimators are very powerful, but rather complex to understand.

#### How do I add another level?

Manually, it's a matter of adding all the missing pieces (activation function, next layer's weights, bias, activation, etc).
That's boring to do by hand.
Luckily, there exist the [`tf.layers` module](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers) that has implementation of layers like dense, conv2d and a ton more (have a look at the link).
Layers are by nature modulars, so making a dnn would be only a matter of stacking `tf.layer.dense()` objects.

Comment: What is considered the best (fastest) way to evaluate a model (like the one above) once trained? Since I was able to fix the code (thanks!) I notice that I can only evaluate a few ~10 rows per second. I'd like to do hundreds per second.

Comment: Sounds like you're running on your CPU. You won't get significantly faster speeds unless you switch to GPU execution.